# How can we perform condition checking between two tables in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, data-manipulation, r-package

Suppose if I consider two tables Transaction and account
where `transaction$account_id` contains factors and unique values in `account$account_id`

```
> transaction
      trans_id account_id amount
             1        100    500
             2        101    200
             3        102    100
             4        100    600
             5        100    700
             6        100    900
             7        101   1000
             8        101  10000
             9        102  20000
            10        101   5000
> account
  account_id Total.amnt notrans transavg
         100       2700       4      675
         101      16200       4     4050
         102      20100       2    10050
```

Now my question is, how to find whether `amount` in `transaction` table is greater than `transavg` in `account` table for each `account_id`.

And store it in a variable with factors as 1 if greater than `transavg` and 0 if lesser than `transavg`. And what packages do I need to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `match`  to compare the `account_id` and then get the corresponding `amount` from the `account` table and then compare it with `amount` in `transaction` table. This will return a boolean output which can be converted to integer using `as.integer`.

```
transaction$flag <- as.integer(transaction$amount > 
          account$transavg[match(transaction$account_id, account$account_id)])

transaction

#   trans_id account_id amount flag
#1         1        100    500    0
#2         2        101    200    0
#3         3        102    100    0
#4         4        100    600    0
#5         5        100    700    1
#6         6        100    900    1
#7         7        101   1000    0
#8         8        101  10000    1
#9         9        102  20000    1
#10       10        101   5000    1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a non-equi join with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(transaction)`), create the 'flag' as 0, join with 'amount' `on` 'account_id' and `amount > transavg`, and assign (`:=`) 'flag' as 1.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(transaction)[, flag := 0][amount, flag := 1, on =.(account_id, amount > transavg)]
transaction
#     trans_id account_id amount flag
# 1:        1        100    500    0
# 2:        2        101    200    0
# 3:        3        102    100    0
# 4:        4        100    600    0
# 5:        5        100    700    1
# 6:        6        100    900    1
# 7:        7        101   1000    0
# 8:        8        101  10000    1
# 9:        9        102  20000    1
#10:       10        101   5000    1
```